# MySQL PHP - Fatal error, query fails on page but not PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query containing a MySQL variable to produce a running total of a time value, and it works and produces results/rows in PHPMyAdmin, but as soon as I try it on my site it produces `"Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object"`. If anyone could help me identify the issue here it would be greatly appreciated.

**Query used in PHPMyAdmin [works]:**

```
SET @total_duration := 0;
SELECT sec_to_time(@total_duration := @total_duration + time_to_sec(duration)) AS cumulative_duration
FROM tbl_flights
ORDER BY tbl_flights.flight_id ASC
```

**Query within PHP file [does not work]:**

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$sql = "SET @total_duration := 0;
        SELECT sec_to_time(@total_duration := @total_duration + time_to_sec(duration)) AS cumulative_duration
        FROM tbl_flights
        ORDER BY tbl_flights.flight_id ASC";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row['cumulative_duration'];

}

?>
```

Comment: That's two queries in one. Either break it apart into two query lines, or use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). You can check for errors with [mysqli_error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Comment: @aynber Could you please highlight where it needs to be split apart? Is `"SET @total_duration := 0;"` a query in itself?

Comment: Yes. Queries/statements end with a semi-colon (or `\G`, but that's usually just for the command line). So that's where it should be broken apart.

Comment: @aynber I had no idea, thought it could work as one query. If you would like to create an answer and I will mark as correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysqli_query can only handle one query at a time. You have two options:

Break it apart into two queries:

```
$sql = "SELECT sec_to_time(@total_duration := @total_duration + time_to_sec(duration)) AS cumulative_duration
        FROM tbl_flights
        ORDER BY tbl_flights.flight_id ASC";
$conn->query("SET @total_duration := 0");
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Or use mysqli_multi_query:

```
$sql = "SET @total_duration := 0;
        SELECT sec_to_time(@total_duration := @total_duration + time_to_sec(duration)) AS cumulative_duration
        FROM tbl_flights
        ORDER BY tbl_flights.flight_id ASC";

$result = $conn->multi_query($sql);
```